# Cassandra with react, net.socket error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cassandra

I am a  newwbie to react and cassandra. I am just trying to connect to the cassandra db by using "npm i cassandra-driver".

I am having a main.js file where I used the cassandra driver code.

Main.js

```
import 'babel-polyfill';
import 'whatwg-fetch';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FastClick from 'fastclick';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

import store from './core/store';
import router from './core/router';
import history from './core/history';

const cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
const client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], keyspace: 'excelsior'}); 
console.log("client---->",client);
const query = 'SELECT * FROM playlists';

client.execute(query, [], function(err, result) {
    console.log("err----->",err);
    console.log("result----->",result);
  assert.ifError(err);
  //console.log('got user profile with email ' + result.rows[0].email);
});

let routes = require('./routes.json'); // Loaded with utils/routes-loader.js
const container = document.getElementById('container');

function renderComponent(component) {
  ReactDOM.render(<Provider store={store}>{component}</Provider>, container);
}

// Find and render a web page matching the current URL path,
// if such page is not found then render an error page (see routes.json, core/router.js)
function render(location) {
  router.resolve(routes, location)
    .then(renderComponent)
    .catch(error => router.resolve(routes, { ...location, error }).then(renderComponent));
}
 continued code ......
```

I am getting the client console, But After that i am getting an error like

```
connection.js:122 Uncaught TypeError: net.Socket is not a constructor(…)
```

Am I missing something here. or is this piece of code should be written anywhere else. ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to run this in client code (i.e. a browser)? I ask because the use of react/redux/etc. is commonly used there.

Comment: @LukeTillman : yeah... or with redux how can i connect this ?

Answer (score 1):

The `cassandra-driver` is meant to be run on a Node.js server, not in the client (i.e. browser).

So, you'll need to create a Node.js server of some kind for your client code (using React, Redux, or whatever) to talk to. For example, in a typical web application setup, your client code in the browser will:

- make an HTTP call to the server
- the server will process that call and use the `cassandra-driver` to go get the appropriate data for that call
- then send the appropriate data back to the client in the HTTP response

This is a pretty gross simplification of how things could be setup, but this type of communication is common for many web applications, regardless of whether they're using Cassandra, Postgres, or whatever database on the server.